# After latest update of Xcode (10.2), Web Inspector is not working

Tags: xcode, web, wkwebview

I've posted this as a bug on Apple's Bug Report site. I thought I'd post here too and see what I can find out as to how I might fix this...

## Area:

Debugging WKWebView with Xcode using Web Inspector in Safari.
I'm running on MacOS Mojave Version: 10.14.3 (18D42).

## Summary:

After letting upgrade of Xcode run (Version 10.2 (10E125)), when I pick the proper Device option from Safari's [Develop] menu (Version 12.0.3 (14606.4.5) of Safari), the Web Inspector comes up while running the app like before, but it displays as basically blank and useless.

## Steps to Reproduce:

1- start iOS app in the Simulator that has a WKWebView that is successfully displaying a web page that has runnable JavaScript in it.
[image: Here I've picked the iPhone 6 Simulator]
*(Figure 1) Here I've picked the iPhone 6 Simulator in Xcode*

.
[image: running app]
*(Figure 2) App running in simulator... WKWebView takes whole screen*

.
[image]
*(Figure 3) screen after clicking [Run Db Startup Code] button (notice new info under "Test Info:")*

.
[image]
*(Figure 4) JS code that runs when this button is clicked.*

.
2-Go to Safari window and pick [Develop] menu.

3- Pick Simulator option for the device like:
    Simulator -- iPhone 6 -- iOS 12.2 (16E226)

4- Pick the "index.html" option
[image]
*(Figure 5)  Picking option in Safari after app in iPhone Simulator has been started*

.

5- Web Inspector comes up, but none of the page's resources are listed (including index.html)
[image]
*(Figure 6) Web Inspector brought up ... this is the Debugger tab. Nothing appears.*

.

[image]
*(Figure 7) Web Inspector, Resources tab... also blank. Clicking the Refresh button above the Network tab does nothing.*

.

6 - Clicking the Web Inspector's refresh button does nothing

## Expected Results:

Resources to load, 
to be able to set break-points on JavaScript lines of code.
to have JS code stopped on any debugger;  statement
to be able to step through JS code and examine current JS variable values.

## Actual Results:

As said before, the web inspector window comes up basically empty (like there is no page loaded into the WKWebView at all (even though there is and I can visually see that JS code runs when I click buttons on test interface).

Note: If I try running on actual tethered device, NO option shows up in Safari's [Developer] menu!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Managed to resolve it updating the OS to 10.14.4 and correspondingly the Safari to 12.1.

Comment: That did it! I updated the OS and everything worked.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

Nothing worked for me... but then I found Safari Technology Preview https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/ - installing this latest version of safari did the trick for me.

Answer (score 2):

After updating to iOS 13 and Safari 13, the connected iPhone did not show up in Safari either. The solution was also for me, to clear the trusted computers on the iPhone under the developer settings and reconnect the iPhone:
[clear the trusted computers on the iPhone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HC4dn.png)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with a remote device (simulator didn't work either). A system update of my macOS (including Safari) fixed it for me.

Seems like the latest iOS Safari Update was incompatible with the last macOS Safari.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 13: for me the solution was to Clear Trusted Computers in Settings, Developer, then reconnect the USB cable, tap Trust this computer, and my iPhone instantly showed in Safari's Develop menu.